# "There has been an error processing your request" - Errors displayed on frontend even though display_errors = 0

Tags: error, security

Magento is displaying the MySQL query and a stack trace on catalog pages.

I can't figure out where it's coming from. DB queries should not be displaying on the frontend, for security reasons.

Do you have any idea how I can turn this off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit/create errors/local.xml and change action from "print" to "none".

Comment: This prevented the SQL from being exposed on the frontend. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `index.php`, is `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` reachable in any way? Try commenting it out.

Comment: I have `if(isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) { Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); }` in index.php. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but try commenting the `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` out and see if you still get stack traces. Also try @Joe's answer as that could be the solution.